# C#, How can I actively query the crypto-market?

Tags: cryptography, c#, currencies

Are there any wrappers to get the real-time crypto-currency value similar to [coincap.io](http://coincap.io/)?

Right now I am using Json to deserialize a download string from [CoinMarketCap](https://coinmarketcap.com/), however, the api does not actively check the real-time value, like coincap.io. Was wondering if there is a wrapper that checks real-time activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try cryptocompare:

https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/#-api-web-socket-

The web socket gives you real-time market data, and their api is quite good also.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for more than just price data, Coinigy is another option. https://www.coinigy.com/

I found their API easy to implement and very reliable and they covered all the exchanges I was interested in.